# Как записать и сохранить аудио в браузере?

Tags: webrtc

Друзья, гуглил все что можно ответов нет...Необходимо записать аудо с микрофона пользователя и отправить на сервер (точно также как аудио сообщения в вк. Есть такая штука как web audio api но она на столько новая что ничего по существу я не нашел...С помощью WebRTC пытался тоже никак...подскажите пожалуйста как это осуществить?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.jRecorder(     
 { 
 host : 'ваш_урл_куда_сохранять_записанный_файл_wav'  ,
 callback_started_recording:     function(){callback_started(); },
 callback_stopped_recording:     function(){callback_stopped(); },
 callback_activityLevel:          function(level){callback_activityLevel(level); },
 callback_activityTime:     function(time){callback_activityTime(time); },
 callback_finished_sending:     function(time){ callback_finished_sending() },
 swf_path : 'jRecorder.swf',
 }
);
```

Кусок скрипта для вашей цели. Подробней читайте в [статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/172299/)

Comment: Видел эту статью говорю же гуглил все что можно...Это не то что нужно там флэш...А мне с помощью WebAudioApi нужно и WebRTC